# Git merging/rebasing strategy for single user development

Tags: c++, git, branching-and-merging, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm using git for a c++ project, and I'm the sole developer.  In addition to maintaining code history, I'm using git because I want to be able to test a new feature without modifying the original code until I'm ready to incorporate the new feature into the original code.  I'm using Github, but I'm the only developer.

So, here is how I imagine my commit history might look (arrows denote child commits, and arrows between branches are implied):

```
         A1 ---> A2 ---> A3        B1 ---> B2
         /                \        /        \
X1 ---> X2  ----------->  X3 ---> X4 -----> X5 ---> (...)
```

In the above history, `A` and `B` represent features (or changes) that I made.  In this history, I worked on `A` first, and then after finishing `A` I started `B`.  Obviously there may come times when I'm working on separate new features in parallel, but in this hypothetical example (and probably most of the time in my actual development), features are worked on in a serial fashion.

In this context, I have two related questions.  I believe it is appropriate to consolidate both questions into a single SO post.

**(1) Does it make sense to only create 1 "new feature" branch (e.g., testing) to run alongside master that will be used to develop both `A` and `B` (and subsequent new features)?** (If so, how would I manage this process of switching between master and testing, merging or rebasing testing back into master, and then switching to testing again to work on another new feature?)

**(2) Given that I'm the only developer would it make more sense to merge or rebase when incorporating a new feature into master?**  I'm new to git, so please explain why.  If the answer is "it depends", please explain how to decide between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this model at my place of employment, and I think it works good:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

So here are some assumptions from that link:

Master is always 100 percent stable all the time always.

Master gets a merge from develop when develop is stable and finished.

For each feature, you make a branch from develop.

When the feature is stable, you merge the feature branch up to develop.

You test all features added to develop to ensure everything that you have added is stable 
with each other feature you have done.

Then merge back up to master when that is all 100 percent.

1:
Given if 'feature' A and B overlap significantly, or are highly dependant on each other, it may be wise to develop both in the same branch.
If they dont, and you get problems on the develop test, you can knock features out whilst debugging as a method of diagnosis. Its your call.
However, you may have to merge develop down into your feature branches should that get farther ahead than you think, mainly because other people will have committed stuff that may conflict with your current branch, should you bring someone else in on it.

I personally like having a feature per branch, and its just a little work to get the stuff from develop back into your branch. That does take a little work sometimes since you have to get changes from develop. Its a tradeoff, really.

As for having one feature running parallel: You can have as many feature branches as you like. So, if you get bored of the feature you are currently working on, just make a new branch from develop and work on that. You address any merge problems in develop before it goes to master.

2:
We cant use rebase in the context you specified, since we are sharing our branches with other people. Id say just use merge so if you do bring someone else into the mix, and voila, no trouble. 
Also this:

http://www.jarrodspillers.com/2009/08/19/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-avoiding-rebase-hell/

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make new branches for each feature. Branches are extremely cheap in Git (literally just writing 41 bytes to a file) and easy to manage.
2. It depends, but not as much as you think. Either way, you'll end up with the same code. The question is what do you want the graph of your history to look like. Rebasing all the time results in a linear history; that's easy to reason about. Branching with merge commits preserves information about exactly when you started a feature and when you merged it in relative to other branches. Sometimes that information is useful, sometimes it's just noise. To make things more confusing, the default `git merge` only sometimes creates merge commits (it will do a fast-forward merge if possible).

   If you want a history graph that looks like your graph above, you need to do both:

   ```
   git checkout feature/foo
   git rebase master
   git checkout master
   git merge --no-ff feature/foo
   ```

   The only concrete advice I have here is that you should not rewrite (rebase) history that you have shared with others.

Comment: Thanks.  So, other than having a potentially "messy" history tree, there's no problem for me using merge all the time in my situation?

Comment: `git merge` will suit you just fine.

Comment: When you say `feature/foo`, are you simply using a forward slash in the branch name?  Or are you referring to some sort of sub-branch?

Comment: The former; `/` is a valid character in branch names.